# How are going to read a text file and auto save in c #

Tags: c#, messagebox

ex: if the text file has the apple - `Messagebox.Show("This word is exist");`

else

`Messagebox.Show("The word does not exist!");`
and if none of these words in the text file will be automatically saved
and automatic make a new line for word does not exist in the text file.

Comment: what exactly is it you are asking for?

Comment: Only you can say how you are going to read the text file etc... Where is the problem? ("Questions must describe a *specific* problem and show *minimal understanding*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read all text

```
  string fileText = File.ReadAllText("filePath");
  if (fileText.Contains("apple"))
  {
       Messagebox.Show("This word is exist");
  }
  else
  {
       Messagebox.Show("The word does not exist!");
       File.AppendAllText(@"filePAth", "The word does not exixt in the text file" + Environment.NewLine);
  }
```

Comment: thanks.. all 2 answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

**One way:**

To read a file, you have to use a `TextReader` in C#:

```
TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"YOUR PATH HERE");
```

After the creation of the `TextReader`-object you can read the whole text of the file via:

```
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

After you read the file, you can close the `TextReader`:

```
reader.Close();
```

**Another way (no `TextReader`)**

You can use `File.ReadAllText(@"YOUR PATH HERE");`

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(@"YOUR PATH HERE");
```

To search a `string` or text for a specific word, use `string.Contains("your word here");`

This will return a `bool` whether the string contains the word or not:

```
bool contains = string.Contains("your word here");
```

- contains = true -> word is in the text.
- contains = false -> word is not in the text.

Based on the value of `contains`, you can now show the `MessageBox`.

I always suggest to use `using` when it you work with Stream- or TextReaders/Writers, so you don't have to handle the disposing and flush/close the reader/writer:

```
using(TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"YOUR PATH HERE")){
     string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
} //No closing needed here (close will automatically be called, when the object gets disposed
```

Comment: You can use File.ReadAllText(...); if you read the whole content into memory anyway...

Comment: Exists since 2.0 -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.80).aspx